# C++ - Constructor, Copy Constructor, Move Constructor, Destructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, destructor, move

I am trying C++ myself, and I really am getting a little confused.
I really got problems with understanding constructor / Copy Constructor/ Move Constructor / Destructor and setting them up correctly.

I want to implement a copy as well as a move constructor and a destructor into the `class Container`. I tried the copy constructor first and thought I got it right. Unfortunately, the destructor lets the program crash at the end for some reason when trying to do `delete[] data`.
I think I got something wrong before that the field `data` is not there anymore and I copied it wrong or whatever.  I hope you can help me out and understand my errors. 
I also tried a move constructor (underneath), which absolutely does not work.

Thanks for the help guys. Hope to be able to give something back later on :)

Container class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Container
{
public:
Container()
{
    length = 0;
    data = nullptr;
}

Container(int lengthin):Container()
{
    length = lengthin;
    data = new double[lengthin];
    //data[lengthin];
    //double data[lengthin] = {0};
}

Container(std::initializer_list<double> listin)
        :Container((int)listin.size())
{
    std::uninitialized_copy ( listin.begin(), listin.end(), data);
}

//copy constructor - working? 
Container(const Container& other):Container(other.length)
{
    //data = other.data;
    //length = other.length;
    for (auto i=0; i<other.length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = other.data[i];
    }
}


//~Container(){length = 0;}
~Container()
{
    delete[] data;
    length = 0;
}


Container operator+(Container cin)
{
    Container cout(cin.length);
    cout.length = cin.length;
    for (auto i=0; i<cin.length; i++)
    {
        cout.data[i] = cin.data[i] + data[i];
    }
    return cout;
}

Container operator-(Container cin)
{
    Container cout(cin.length);
    cout.length = cin.length;
    for (auto i=0; i<cin.length; i++)
    {
        cout.data[i] = data[i]-cin.data[i];
    }
    return cout;
}


void print(const std::string &info) const
{
    // print the address of this instance, the attributes `length` and
    // `data` and the `info` string
    std::cout << "  " << this << " " << length << " " << data << "  "
              << info << std::endl;
}

private:
    int length;
    double *data;
};
```

The main programme:

```
int main()
{
Container a({ 1, 2, 3 });
std::cout << "  a has address " << &a << std::endl;

Container b = { 4, 5, 6 };  
std::cout << "  b has address " << &b << std::endl;

Container c(a);
std::cout << "  c has address " << &c << std::endl;

Container d = a + b;
std::cout << "  d has address " << &d << std::endl;

Container e;
std::cout << "  e has address " << &e << std::endl;

e = a + b;

//Container f(std::move(a + b));   
//std::cout << "  f has address " << &f << std::endl;

return 0;}
```

And the tried move constructor:

```
Container(const Container&& other):length(other.length), data(other.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your move constructor doesn't *move* anything, it just copies the length and pointer (meaning it works just like the default copy-constructor). That means you will have two `Container` objects whose `data` member will point to the same memory.

When one of the object that memory is deleted, leading to *undefined behavior* when the second object tries to delete the same memory.

A simple way to fix this is to set the other objects `length` to zero and its `data` pointer to `nullptr`. Or default-initialize the current object, and then swap the two objects.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by Some programmer dude, this move constructor would do :

```
Container(Container&& other):length(other.length), data(other.data)
{
other.length = 0;
other.data = nullptr;
}
```

`other.data = nullptr;` therefore when other's destructor is called, `delete []data` will have no effect (with your current code is invalidates the data array held by the Container you just moved to.
`other.length = 0;` Because since other has no data array, it also should have no length.
Note that I only posted the code because apparently you have posted a wrong answer yourself (it seems like the first answer wasn't clear enough as to what the code should be).
Also because this is a constructor your do not have to worry about `this->data` note that with a move asignement operator you would have to first `delete this->data[]` in order to avoid memory leak.

The copy asignement function could be as such :

```
Container& operator=(const Container &other)
{
    if (this->length)
    delete[] this->data;
    this -> length = other.length;
    data = new double [this->length];
    for (auto i = 0; i<other.length; i++)
    {
        this->data[i] = other.data[i];
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your copy constructor is fine (but can be simplified using a copy algorithm instead of a manual loop).

Your class is missing a copy assignment operator, a move constructor, and a move assignment operator.

And your `operator+` and `operator-` should take their inputs by reference instead of by value, and themselves be declared as `const`.  They are also not taking into account that the input `Container` may have a different `length` than the `Container` being acted on.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class Container
{
public:
    Container() : length(0), data(nullptr)
    {
    }

    Container(int len) : Container()
    {
        length = len;
        data = new double[len];
    }

    Container(std::initializer_list<double> src) : Container((int)src.size())
    {
        std::uninitialized_copy(src.begin(), src.end(), data);
    }

    Container(const Container &src) : Container(src.length)
    {
        std::uninitialized_copy(src.data, src.data + src.length, data);
    }

    Container(Container &&src) : Container()
    {
        src.swap(*this);
    }

    ~Container()
    {
        delete[] data;
        length = 0;
    }

    void swap(Container &other) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(data, other.data);
        std::swap(length, other.length);
    }

    Container& operator=(const Container &rhs)
    {
        if (length < rhs.length)
        {
            Container tmp(rhs);
            swap(tmp);
        }
        else
        {
            length = rhs.length;
            std::uninitialized_copy(rhs.data, rhs.data + rhs.length, data);
        }
        return *this;        
    }

    Container& operator=(Container&& rhs)
    {
        rhs.swap(*this);
        return *this;        
    }

    Container operator+(const Container &rhs) const
    {
        int len = std::max(length, rhs.length);
        Container out(len);
        for (auto i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            if ((i < length) && (i < rhs.length))
                out.data[i] = data[i] + rhs.data[i];
            else
                out[i] = (i < length) ? data[i] : rhs.data[i];
        }
        return out;
    }

    Container operator-(const Container &rhs) const
    {
        int len = std::max(length, rhs.length);
        Container out(len);
        for (auto i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            if ((i < length) && (i < rhs.length))
                out.data[i] = data[i] - rhs.data[i];
            else
                out[i] = (i < length) ? data[i] : rhs.data[i];
        }
        return out;
    }

    void print(const std::string &info) const
    {
        // print the address of this instance, the attributes `length` and
        // `data` and the `info` string
        std::cout << " " << this << " " << length << " " << data << " " << info << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int length;
    double *data;
};

namespace std
{
    void swap(Container &lhs, Container &rhs)
    {
        lhs.swap(rhs);
    }
}
```

And then you can greatly simplify things by using `std::vector` instead of a manual array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Container
{
public:
    Container(size_t len = 0) : data(len)
    {
    }

    Container(std::initializer_list<double> src) : data(src)
    {
    }

    void swap(Container &other) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(data, other);
    }

    Container operator+(const Container &rhs) const
    {
        size_t thislen = data.size();
        size_t thatlen = rhs.data.size();
        size_t len = std::max(thislen, thatlen);
        Container out(len);
        for (auto i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            if ((i < thislen) && (i < thatlen))
                out.data[i] = data[i] + rhs.data[i];
            else
                out[i] = (i < thislen) ? data[i] : rhs.data[i];
        }
        return out;
    }

    Container operator-(const Container &rhs) const
    {
        size_t thislen = data.size();
        size_t thatlen = rhs.data.size();
        size_t len = std::max(thislen, thatlen);
        Container out(len);
        for (auto i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            if ((i < thislen) && (i < thatlen))
                out.data[i] = data[i] - rhs.data[i];
            else
                out[i] = (i < thislen) ? data[i] : rhs.data[i];
        }
        return out;
    }

    void print(const std::string &info) const
    {
        // print the address of this instance, the attributes `length` and
        // `data` and the `info` string
        std::cout << " " << this << " " << data.size() << " " << data.data() << " " << info << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::vector<double> data;
};

namespace std
{
    void swap(Container &lhs, Container &rhs)
    {
        lhs.swap(rhs);
    }
}
```